# Antiderivatives: A car is traveling at $50 mi/h$ when the brakes are fully applied........

Tags: calculus

A car is traveling at $50   mi /h$ when the brakes are fully applied, producing a constant deceleration of $38 ft/s^2$. What is the distance covered before the car comes to a stop?

Since the car is decelerating, our value will be negative.

$v'(t)= a(t)=-38$ so $v(t)= -38x= s(t)-38x^2/(2)$ After this point I am not sure what I am supposed to do? Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well let us first attempt to get our units the same. For miles/hour we can rewrite this as $\frac{220}{3}$ feet per second.

We are given an acceleration, an initial velocity, and are asked for a distance.

So, $$\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = a \implies vdv = adx$$

Integrating from initial velocity given to 0, and using the given acceleration, we find:

$$0 - \frac{1}{2}(\frac{220}{3})^2 = (-38) \Delta x$$

Or,

$$\Delta x = 70.7602 ft$$

Comment: I like the way you wrote and explained your answer. Well done.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate that.